# Splash screen is not getting displayed even using <intent-filter> in it

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I just want to show my splash screen before any activity.
I don't have anything in my main activity all the stuff is designed on my splash screen. So, I tried this code to make the splash screen visible before I make the main activity be visible.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash_Screen"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>
```

But this shows me the blank page (looks like it is running the main activity).
Why the splash screen is not visible at first?

Comment: first of all you can only set `exported=true` to only on activity but here u have setted `true` in both activity. and second is nor you setted a splash screen theme or showed what have you done in `Splash_Screen` activity

Comment: you can check this doc of splash screen it may help you [Splash screens](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen)

Comment: brother pls share Splash_Screen code so that we can have more information, also the xml if needed

Comment: Most likely you're looking for something like [this](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336). Here's the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication).

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue in two steps.

1)-   I set the value of exported to false for every activity including `main activity` like

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:exported="false"
```

and in the case of splash screen, I set the value to true like

```
android:name=".Splash_Screen"
android:exported="true">
```

2)- I change the configuration to `app` from `MainActivity` by

```
Run > Edit Configurations
```

Under the Run/Debug Configuration panel switch `MainActivity` to `app`.
This made my application run and also now the splash screen is working as expected.